# Writing a cache-everything/quick-response HTTP proxy

Tags: http, caching, open-source, proxy, http-proxy

**Are there any open source HTTP caching proxies I can use to give myself a good starting point?**

I want to write a personal HTTP caching proxy to achieve the following purposes

1. Serve content instantly even if the remote site is slow
2. Serve content even if the network is down
3. Allow me to read old content if I'd like to

Why do I want to do this?

1. The speed of Internet connection in my area is far from spectacular.
2. I want to cache contents even if the HTTP headers tell me not to
3. **I really don't like it when I couldn't quickly access content that I've read in the past.**
4. I feel powerless when a website removes useful content and I find no way to get it back

The project comprises

1. A proxy running it on the local network (or perhaps on localhost), and
2. A browser plugin or a desktop program to show content-updated notifications

What's special about the proxy?

1. The browser initiates an HTTP request
2. The proxy **serves the content first**, if it's already in the cache
3. **Then** the proxy contacts the remote website and **check whether the content has been updated**
4. If the content has been updated, send a notification to the desktop/browser (e.g. to show a little popup or change the color of a plug-in icon), and download the content in the background.
5. *Every time* the proxy download new content, save it into the cache
6. Let me choose to load the updated content or not (if not, stop downloading the new content; if yes, stream the new content to me)
7. Let me assign rules to always/never load fresh content from certain websites
8. Automatically set the rules if the proxy finds that (1) I always want to load fresh content from a certain website, or (2) the website's content frequently updates

Note:

1. Caching everything does not pose a security problem, as I'm the only one with physical access to the proxy, and the proxy is only serving me (from the local network)
2. I think this is technologically feasible (let me know if you see any architectural problems)
3. I haven't decided whether I should keep old versions of the webpages. But given that my everyday bandwidth usage is just 1-2 GB, a cheap 1TB hard drive can easily hold two years of data!

**Does my plan make sense? Any suggestions/objections/recommedations?**

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at polipo:
http://www.pps.univ-paris-diderot.fr/~jch/software/polipo/

Source is here:
https://github.com/jech/polipo

It is a caching web proxy implemented in C. It should definitely help you.